Image Target Vuforia engine problems
I tried to enable vuforia AR support, but in XR setting under player settings, there is no option called Vuforia augmented reality support.
Before, I've done this and it worked. Does it work now on the new version of Unity? Vuforia Engine 10.22 should be compatible with Unity 2021.3.5f1. If not, which version do I need?  Is there anything specific I need to pay attention to?
I installed unity 2021.3.5f1 and vuforia engine i
Vuforia Engine 10.22 and some errors keep appearing

XR setting can you elaborate this?

Have you looked at this guide? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-unity
